# Como aparecer ícone na action Bar quando item estiver no overflow?

Tags: android, android-layout

**Eu queria que o item chamada também aparecesse do seu lado sua imagem:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**O resultado que esperaria seria esse:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código da activity com ajuda do @Alexandre Strevenski:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
        MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.acao4);
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider)
                MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(shareItem);
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultIntent());

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private Intent getDefaultIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        return intent;
    }
}
```

**main_activity_actions.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/acao1"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="deletar"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/acao2"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="adicionar"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/acao3"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="camera"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/acao4"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_call"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="chamada"
        yourapp:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"/>

</menu>
```

**Obs: já utilizei android:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider" e também não da certo.**

**Log do Erro:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você está falando especificamente do `ShareActionProvider` ou de item/subitem qualquer que você esteja fazendo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se a idéia e ter ícones nos menus do `Overflow Menu` e não com `ActionProvider` então precisa usar `Reflection` para resolver, dado que por padrão não são exibidos ícones.

No caso, basta implementar o método `onMenuOpened` na sua `Activity` e chamar o método `setOptionalIconsVisible`, que é privado`do`Menu`por`Reflection`:

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu) {
    if(featureId == Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR && menu != null){
        if(menu.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("MenuBuilder")){
            try{
                Method m = menu.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setOptionalIconsVisible", Boolean.TYPE);
                m.setAccessible(true);
                m.invoke(menu, true);
            } catch(NoSuchMethodException e){
            } catch(Exception e){
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    return super.onMenuOpened(featureId, menu);
}
```

Para usar em conjunto com o `ActionMode`, a única alteração foi chamar o método para o `Menu` que é passado na callback `onCreateActionMode`. O código ficaria:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = actionMode.getMenuInflater();

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_cab, menu);

    // Reaproveitando o método para habilitar os ícones.
    onMenuOpened(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR, menu);

    return true;
}
```

É claro que fiz uma simplificação para reaproveitamento do `onMenuOpened`, mas a ideia é isolar o método e chamar nos dois métodos, tanto no `onMenuOpened` quanto no `onCreateActionMode`.

A configuração do `MenuItem` no xml continua a mesma:

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_alarm"
      android:title="@string/action_alarm"
      android:icon="?attr/ic_action_alarm"
      appcompat:showAsAction="never"
      android:showAsAction="never"
/>
```

Essa é a solução que funciona, mas caso em futuras versões do Android, venha a mudar algo nessa classe (`Menu`) ou caso você venha a usar o `Toolbar`, essa solução não irá mais funcionar. Ai terá que adotar alguma uma medida de contingência.

Comment: muito obrigado deu certo^^ mas quando eu utilizar action mode tem como fazer o mesmo efeito?

Comment: Não cheguei a testar com o `ActionMode`, posso testar se irá funcionar.

Comment: hum.. blz agradeço mesmo^^ eu tinha testado aki e não funcionou na realidade e porque to usando fragment e não posso usar esse método .

Comment: Acho que não faz sentido, o `Menu` pertence à `Activity`, mesmo que o `Fragment` tenha menu's. Testei com o `ActionMode` e funcionou, vou incluir a alteração no código.

Comment: muito obrigado deu certo^^ Você me salvou de verdade.

Answer (score 2):

Tu pode seguir o exemplo neste link:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionProvider

**O XML ficaria assim:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_share"
          android:title="@string/share"
          yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"
          yourapp:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
          />
    ...
</menu>
```

**Exemplo de código utilizando o ShareActionProvider:**

```
private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);

    // Set up ShareActionProvider's default share intent
    MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider)
            MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(shareItem);
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultIntent());

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/** Defines a default (dummy) share intent to initialize the action provider.
  * However, as soon as the actual content to be used in the intent
  * is known or changes, you must update the share intent by again calling
  * mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent()
  */
private Intent getDefaultIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    return intent;
}
```

Comment: essa linha yourapp:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider" da erro....

Comment: coloquei a imagem do erro...

Comment: @PedroRangel onde esta 'yourapp' coloca 'android'

Comment: Se não der, tenta substituir o 'yourapp:' por apenas 'app:'

Comment: com android deu certo, mas da erro na hora da execução falando q nao existe essa classe.. coloquei a imagem no post

Comment: Da uma olhada nesse link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19123543/classcastexception-android-support-v7-widget-shareactionprovider-to-action-view

Comment: Ou esse link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120447/classcastexception-android-support-v7-widget-shareactionprovider

Comment: ja fiz isso mas nao da certo

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente add a linha abaixo em seu menunovo.XML

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

segunto coloque o seguinte atributo em seu item

```
app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

alem do seu icone.

no meu teste eu fiz isso:
meu menu2.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.teste.MainActivity" 
xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    />

 </menu>
```

o meu main ficou assim:

```
package com.example.teste;
```

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);
    MenuInflater inflater2 = getMenuInflater();
    inflater2.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

se precisar de mais alguma coisa grita ae

Comment: qual atributo do xml faz com que fique do jeito do meu post?

Comment: calma agora entendi o que vc quer fazer... 
deixa eu ver, ja respondo se eu conseguir
vou fazer meus testes aqui

Comment: de boas^^ vlw por tentar agradeco

Comment: olhando groceiramente eu tiraria o > antes do erro
e tiraria a / do /> depois do yourapp

Comment: editei a resposta, vela se consegue,qualquer coisa grita, estarei aqui até 17:40 entao anda logo huahsuauhsa
se nao só amanha

Comment: cara acho q você não entendeu ainda.. tipo quando se tem muitos itens.. tem overflow aew aparece só os nomes como na imagem que postei.. queria que aparecesse ao lado o ícone..

Comment: saquei.. eu tava com o mesmo problema, ainda nao resolvi. 
quando vc resolver posta aqui, e se eu resolver te conto como

Comment: de boas^^ a coisa ruim é que no android pequenas coisas(detalhes) as vezes complica de mais...